# Back button redirect me to login page in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-security

I have a very strange bug which I have no idea how to even investigate.

I made a login process following this exact tutorial on Symfony documentation, very simple authentication via login form. I encounter a very strange problem described in the steps below:

1. I go to my /login page
2. I fill the credentials and log in (everything is fine I am moved to the restricted area)
3. I go through the app (different pages)
4. When I click browser back button I am redirected to /login page

What is strange is that:

1. I still have session key in cookies
2. When I write direct URL in the browser to the restricted area I can access it and profiler then show proper user logged in
3. When I am redirected to /login page profiler show anon. user (despite having session cookie)

Not strange enough? Here you go, when I open browser developers tools (on chrome) the bug does not exists and everything works just fine.

I assume something needs to be caching maybe somewhere and that is why it's happening but I have no idea where to look, can someone help me out here, please!

Below I list couple of maybe useful configs:

security.yml

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        #in_memory: { memory: ~ }
        users:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            logout:
                path: logout
                target: login
            remember_me:
                secret: '%kernel.secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path: /
            anonymous: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User: md5
    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/app, roles: ROLE_USER }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

routing.yml

```
framework:
    router:
        strict_requirements: ~
        utf8: true
```

LoginFormAuthenticator.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return 'login' === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'username' => $request->request->get('username'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['username']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['username' => $credentials['username']]);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Username could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_dashboard'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate('login');
    }
}
```

Maybe a useful addition is that everything is running on Apache on Docker.

Please help me out here.

Comment: are you using a full ajax navigation ?

Comment: No, it's a standard routing and navigation as per Symfony documentation.